# how to write multiple nested ng-repeat in blow json format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use multiple nested ng-repeat to bind the data which is in the json format

Here's the code that I have written so far :

```
$scope.LeavesStatastics = {
            "departMentLeaveStatisticss": [
               {
                   "depId": 1,
                   "depName": "System Admin",
                   "employeeStatisticss": [
                      {
                          "empId": 1,
                          "empName": "Rahul",
                          "reportingManagerId": 1,
                          "employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList": [
                             {
                                 "employeeLeaveTypeId": 1,
                                 "leaveName": "something",
                                 "maxLeave": 1,
                                 "totalLeaveTaken": 0.0,
                                 "additionalLeave": 0.0,
                                 "lopLeave": 0.0,
                                 "resetDate": null
                             },
                             {
                                 "employeeLeaveTypeId": 2,
                                 "leaveName": "festival",
                                 "maxLeave": 1,
                                 "totalLeaveTaken": 0.0,
                                 "additionalLeave": 0.0,
                                 "lopLeave": 0.0,
                                 "resetDate": "2016-12-22"
                             },
                             {
                                 "employeeLeaveTypeId": 3,
                                 "leaveName": "Fiver",
                                 "maxLeave": 1,
                                 "totalLeaveTaken": 0.0,
                                 "additionalLeave": 0.0,
                                 "lopLeave": 0.0,
                                 "resetDate": "2017-03-14"
                             }
                          ]
                      }
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "depId": 2,
                   "depName": "Science",
                   "employeeStatisticss": [
                      {
                          "empId": 2,
                          "empName": "Anil",
                          "reportingManagerId": 1,
                          "employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList": [
                             {
                                 "employeeLeaveTypeId": 1,
                                 "leaveName": "something",
                                 "maxLeave": 1,
                                 "totalLeaveTaken": 0.0,
                                 "additionalLeave": 0.0,
                                 "lopLeave": 0.0,
                                 "resetDate": null
                             },
                             {
                                 "employeeLeaveTypeId": 2,
                                 "leaveName": "festival",
                                 "maxLeave": 1,
                                 "totalLeaveTaken": 0.0,
                                 "additionalLeave": 0.0,
                                 "lopLeave": 0.0,
                                 "resetDate": null
                             },
                             {
                                 "employeeLeaveTypeId": 3,
                                 "leaveName": "Fiver",
                                 "maxLeave": 1,
                                 "totalLeaveTaken": 0.0,
                                 "additionalLeave": 0.0,
                                 "lopLeave": 0.0,
                                 "resetDate": "2017-03-13"
                             }
                          ]
                      }
                   ]
               }
            ]
        }
```

Please take a look at the html part that I have written :

```
<tr ng-repeat="y in x.employeeStatisticss">
                    <td>
                        {{ y.empName }}
                    </td>
                    <td ng-repeat="z in y.employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList">
                        {{ z.maxLeave }}
                    </td>
                    <td ng-repeat="z in y.employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList">
                        {{ z.additionalLeave }}
                    </td>
                    <td ng-repeat="z in y.employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList">
                        {{ z.lopLeave }}
                    </td>

               </tr>
```

Please help, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is your JSON? I only see an JavaScript object.

Comment: What is the problem? You gave us the html eements and your json in $scope so what?

Comment: Its not JSON, its an JavaScript Object. JSON looks different. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, while you did not give enough information to create a full qualified answer I tried to put out your data on a random way - this is [runnable demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhr7ayhp/):

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table border="1">
   <tbody ng-repeat="parent in LeavesStatastics.departMentLeaveStatisticss">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in parent.employeeStatisticss">
        <td>{{ item.empName }} </td>
        <td ng-repeat="z in item.employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList">
          {{ z.maxLeave }}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="z in item.employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList">
          {{ z.additionalLeave }}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="z in item.employeeLeaveTypeStatisticsList">
          {{ z.lopLeave }}
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @RakeshAdigoppula seeing your link, you are already iterating through the js object correctly. what is it you want actually?

Comment: @RakeshAdigoppula Please create a new question because this is solced. Dont forget to mark the right answer by using the tick near the answer vote buttons. Imwill help you in your new question.